# Recommendation for `go test` CLI test reporter

Tags: unit-testing, testing, go, report, command-line-interface

I plan to use the golang's `testing` package and `go test` for writing unit tests. I find `go test` only provides coverage report in the CLI, but I cannot find any  `go test` option allowing me to get a summary report for the test suite.

For example, after running tests, I would like to see a minimal test report including the following information:

- how many tests in the test suite
- how many of them pass
- how many of them fail

I did some web search, but cannot find any good golang native option/third party tool/library to support this. And I only found a library https://github.com/jstemmer/go-junit-report that allows me to convert the results into JUnit XML which requires me to do some further processing to get the summary, which is not convenient enough.

I would like to know when working with `go test` and the `testing` package, what is the tool/library people typically use for such test report generation purpose, in particular when running via CLI? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is `gotestsum`, https://github.com/gotestyourself/gotestsum

**Description at github:**

> `go test` runner with output optimized for humans, JUnit XML for CI integration, and a summary of the test results.
>   "

Answer (score 1):

The `go test` command has a variety of [flags](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Description_of_testing_flags) which includes `-v` verbose flag. This option prints test specifics as well as test suite stats.

Comment: No, I don't think the `go test -v` prints any of these stats, it only prints each test name and if individual test passes or not, but there is no summary for the test suite, as I mentioned in the question, I would like to have a minimal summary including the number of tests, number of succeeded tests, number of failed tests.